# Hippo Channelmanager Sitemap not editable

Tags: hippocms

We're stuck in the Hippo Channel Manager when adding a page. The docs say that the option should be enabled when there is a prototype page. Well, we have it, but the Channel Manager says: sitemap not editable. I've tested it with a 'clean' maven generated project with some sample content: same message. Find a screenshot attached. What am I doing wrong?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce this. I have a 11.1 archetype project with simple content (from essentials) and copied the the homepage to the prototype pages. This works. I need more detail about what you have done to know why it doesn't work. In order for this to be activated you have to have a prototype page (obvious) and a workspace. Now you should have a workspace anyway so this should not be the issue, but perhaps you have changed some authorization?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by doing a complete 'reconfigure' from scratch and re-applying all my changes. Sorry for bothering you.